# Pandas Plot Multiple Lines Based on Per Column Trend

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

So I have the following data below, so basically every column after `tree` is a progression of the value of it's values(e.g Tree_0, Tree_1 and etc.)

```
tree,ave_1-2021-06-12,ave_2-2021-06-12,ave_3-2021-06-12
Tree_0,290.7,248.7,247.8
Tree_1,261.1,258.7,221.5
Tree_2,220.0,251.9,233.5
Tree_3,246.3,242.1,275.4
Tree_4,248.3,254.1,243.8
Tree_5,251.4,251.1,261.4
```

I want to be able to make a plot that shows all Tree_* values and shows it's trend based on the ave_* values which are on it's next column, how do I do that with matplotlib and pandas?

For example:

```
Tree_01, linechart starts at 290 goes lower 248 then gows one point lower 247

Tree_02 starts at 261 goes down at 258, goes much lower 221.
```

I want to represent them all in one chart. Like this: [linechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zELiB.png) Tree's will be the legend below and the dates will be the ave_* columns. But I dont know how to do this with pandas and matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first set the Tree column aside as the index and then take the `T`ranspose to put the trees in the legend and `ave_*` to the x-axis:

```
df.set_index("tree").T.plot()
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df.plot(x='tree', y='ave_1-2021-06-12', kind='line')
```

Do this for all your columns, you should be able to see a line chart for all of them.

Comment: this doesnt work,  this gets all Tree_* in one direction https://prnt.sc/153helc If possible I want the Tree's be on the side then the ave_ values below. Something like this: https://prnt.sc/153hi01